# What Office Files Viewers and Editors are available for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ms-office

I'm composing a windows phone 8 application that needs to enable the user to download some excel file, edit it to his will, and upload it back to my server. 
I'm able to easily download the file and opening it with the internal Office app, **but**:

1. I don't want the user to be able to save the file - I want to keep it only accessible via my app.
2. I can't get the file "Back" from the office app.

I consider using some Office Files Viewer (Like [Polaris Office for iOS](http://www.polarisoffice.com/en/Enterprise.asp) SDK), but I can't seem to find any such SDKs.

Can anyone offer a better solution then an using a 3rd party library, or suggest a godd 3rd party library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the ComponentOne Studio for Windows Phone, they have an Excel library http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ExcelPhone/

Syncfusion has a Word and an Excel library, see http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/controls.

I have not found any PowerPoint library.

Comment: But it does not help with Word and PowerPoint...
Any solution to those programs as well?

Comment: This is an year old post. Is there still no official Microsoft library to create/edit Excel spreadsheets on Windows Phone?